# Can't close virtual keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-keyboard

I am developing an app for a touch screen monitor. I can call the Virtual keyboard no problem using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

I am looking to close the keyboard by clicking a button in my application.
In my `onclick` method I have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe").Kill();
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Your attempt to close it will actually open a *second* instance of the keyboard and close it immediately.

Comment: Save a copy of the `Process` that is returned when you `Start` it the first time, and kill *that* process.

Answer (score 5):

`Process.Start` returns a `Process` object. Capture that return value and use it to close the keyboard when the user clicks the button.

```
var osk = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
//Do things

//In your button click event
osk.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble finding a solution for this as well. Even though this question is older I'll post the solution which worked for me if anyone runs into the same problem.

Saving the reference when starting the process **did not work** for me. I still don't know why. What worked is looping through all processes using the process name `osk`.

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("osk"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this instead:

```
Process osk = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

When you are ready to kill it, do this:

```
osk.Kill();
```

The issue with your method is your starting `osk.exe`, then later trying to kill it. But your code to kill it is spinning up a new process and then killing that new spun up process instead of your original process. It's killing it immediately before the OSK is even showing, thus you aren't even seeing the second instance.

Also, know the difference between `osk.Kill()` and `osk.Close()`. `Close()` is the equivalent of hitting the little red X in the upper right hand corner of the window. It allows the application to gracefully shut down on its own. `Kill()` is the equivalent of opening task manager and forcing the process to end. `Close()` is probably what you want.

Comment: im still haveing trouble public Form1()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
          var osk = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
          
        }

Comment: public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             oks.Close();
        }